# iOS UIScrollView, what am I misunderstanding? I cannot get a scrollview to scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I am a pretty new iOS developer and am coming across my first need for a scroll view. The page I need to design is a little complex. Since I was struggling to get that to layout correctly, I decided to create a super simple scene just so I could make sure I understood how to get UIScrollViews to work. Apparently it didn't help as things aren't working and I am stuck after following several tutorials.

I'm working in Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3.

Screenshots at the end of this post.

I have a scene that consists of a scrollview and a child view with two labels in it. I’ve set the labels to be ~700pt apart to try to make scrolling happen. Nothing scrolls and you can only see the first label. Additionally, the child view does not expand to be full height.

You can see in the screen shots that my scroll view has constraints to pin it to the sides of the superview.

The child view has the same.

The label constraints position them within the child view and 700pt from each other. I thought that this would give the views the height they need to make scrolling happen. There are no constraint errors.

I am hoping for the red childview to fill the vertical space and then scroll. At this point I’d take any layout as long as something was scrolling. Nothing is though, what do I not get?

Screenshots:
(removed due to link limit because I'm still a new SO user)

---

EDIT (6/12/16):

I've made some changes and gotten a little closer. Primarily, it was suggested to me elsewhere to set one of the labels to be equal height with the scroll view. This now gives me the "bounce" effect which means stuff is sort of scrolling; however, we're still only dealing with one screen of content as the second label which is hidden below is clipped off.

Here's where things stand:
[edited hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obsiz.png)
[edited screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTdZE.png)

Comment: You need to set the scroll view's content size.  If you don't set it explicitly then it will calculate the size of it's content, which is the size of the child view. Since you have constrained the child view to the scroll view, the child view is the same size as the scroll view.  Try setting the constraints between the child view and the scroll view so that the child view is bigger than the scroll view (e.g. edit "child-view leading == scroll view leading" and set the constant to -300)

Comment: @Paulw11 I thought that having the labels implied the content size? Also I had put a constraint of height = 90 on the content view along with the top/bottom/leading/trailing. Otherwise it was throwing an error. So it does have an explicit height.

Comment: It will try and infer a content size but since you have constrained the view to the scroll view, that is the content size it will end up with, assuming that you want the buttons outside of the visible screen based on the horizontal spacing.  See what happens if you constrain the leading edge of the button to the leading edge of the view and the trailing edge of the other button and keep the spacing. You should end up with a conflict

Comment: I've made a few edits and got closer based on advice off-site. Take a look at the edited screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a `UIScrollView` in a storyboard, you need to ensure that the scroll view is able to compute the size of its content.  If you don't have sufficient constraints then you will get an error in Interface Builder:

> Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity

Clicking the Info icon on this error will advise you that there needs to be constraints touching all sides of the scroll view and to ensure that you can trace a continual line of constraints from left-to-right and top-to-bottom.

You can achieve this with or without the content view you have added.  I will show you how to do it without the content view in scroll view, simply because there are fewer constraints that way and therefore less typing.

1. Add the scroll view to the root view
2. Constrain the top/left/top/bottom of the scroll view to its superview (the root view).  Remember to turn off constrain to margins if you want the full width of the screen
3. Add label 1 and label 2 to the scroll view
4. Constrain top/leading/bottom of label 1 to the scroll view
5. Constrain top/trailing/bottom of label 2 to the scroll view
6. Constrain the trailing edge of label 1 to the leading edge of label 2 with 0 space
7. Constrain label 1 width to be equal to the width of the scroll view
8. Constrain label 1 height to be equal to the height of the scroll view
9. Constrain the width and height of label 2 to be equal to the width and height of label 1
10. There is no step 10 :)

Comment: I was able to get it working! Mine is scrolling vertically, it looks like your example is going horizontal. But the part that I was missing is what you have here with how labels 1 & 2 interact and the equal heights. I'll mark this as correct. Thanks so much for your help and patience!

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood the scroll direction you were after, but as you found the basic approach works in either axis

Answer (score 0):

ScrollViews are particular in that they like to know explicitly how much they are supposed to scroll. The best way I have found to handle this is to have the following hierarchy with some constraints:

```
-Scroll View
    -Content View
        -View (constrained to top, bottom, leading, trailing anchors)
            -Your other views (e.g. Label)
```

By having one View living underneath the Content View and then containing all of your other Views within that View, the ScrollView then knows how much it's supposed to scroll (it just uses the size of the one child View) no matter how much stuff you have inside of the child View.

Let me see if I can snap a picture of an example from one of my projects. In the meantime, give this hierarchy a try and let me know if it works for you. You would probably constrain the Label to the top and leading anchors of the child View and then constrain the height to something taller than the screen (e.g. 1000 units).

Let me know if you have any questions.

Edit: Example hierarchy below

[image: Content View has a child View which holds all of your other Views]